# image and textboxs look weird in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, metro-ui-css

[image]

when I compile the program sometimes it looks like the top image and sometimes like the one on the bottom and I have no clue why

the text on the right is a simple `textbox` and picture on the left is a `metroTile` from [metroFramework](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/) I'm using visual studio 2013, and the project is `Windows form application`

**EDIT**: i have a base form that every form inherit from it and this appears normal on all other windows, only on this windows which the main window it looks like this

Comment: Is there a reason for you to still being stuck with Winforms and some third-party skinning library, instead of using WPF?

Comment: because it is working fine

Comment: Sure doesn't seem so :) Anyway, looks like a rendering issue, which actually seems to exist in both images, it just is much worse in the image below. I can see a bunch of white pixels in the top image. To me this looks like an issue with your skinning library. I'd drop this kind of skinning approach for an officially supported and better suited one like WPF. You will be much better off in the long run.

Comment: maybe on the next project, the wired thing is that yesterday everything was all good and dandy